# groupby_bins on two variables?

Tags: python-xarray

Say I have an array `nl` containing 4124 measurements. Each is associated with a (`lat`, `lon`) couple specifying the location where the measurement took place. These locations are not gridded, i.e. they are not aligned with regularly spaced values.

```
In [51]: whos
Variable   Type         Data/Info
---------------------------------
lat        ndarray      4124: 4124 elems, type `float32`, 16496 bytes
lon        ndarray      4124: 4124 elems, type `float32`, 16496 bytes
nl         ndarray      4124: 4124 elems, type `int16`, 8248 bytes
```

I create a DataArray for `nl`, specifying `lat` and `lon` as coordinates:

```
nl = xr.DataArray(nl, coords={'lon':(['time'], lon), 'lat':(['time'], lat)}, dims=['time'])
```

I know I can group these values in bins of longitude or latitude to operate on them, for instance

```
nl_avg_lon = nl.groupby_bins('lon', np.r_[-180:190:10]).mean()
nl_avg_lat = nl.groupby_bins('lat', np.r_[-90:90:10]).mean()
```

What I'd like to do is group values in 2D bins of longitude x latitude, so I can show the result as a map. I don't think groupby_bins can do that, is there another solution?

**Update with example:**

This is how I'd do what I want with numpy proper:

```
latbins = np.r_[-90:100:10]
lonbins = np.r_[-180:190:10]
nsamples, xx, yy = np.histogram2d(lon, lat, bins=(lonbins, latbins))
nl_sum, xx, yy = np.histogram2d(lon, lat, bins=(lonbins, latbins), weights=nl)
nl_avg = nl_sum / nsamples
```

I'd like to avoid resorting to numpy to keep xarray's integration with dash.

Answer (score 2):

Grouping by more than one dimension is currently being worked on, but isn't yet available in xarray.

In the meantime there are some very tolerable workarounds. For example, if you create a third coordinate which is the concat of `lat` & `lon`, you can group by that coordinate to generate a set `lat x lon` bins

Here's a brief example:

```
In [12]: da=xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(3,3,2), dims=['lat','lon','time'])

In [13]: da
Out[13]: 
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 3, lon: 3, time: 2)>
array([[[ 0.69092373,  0.94961267],
        [ 0.74086633,  0.22628054],
        [ 0.08215398,  0.16806347]],

       [[ 0.67699002,  0.86242477],
        [ 0.54688503,  0.57882117],
        [ 0.21120849,  0.68743872]],

       [[ 0.43816928,  0.57682212],
        [ 0.10402045,  0.78923986],
        [ 0.53284326,  0.23705761]]])
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) int64 0 1 2
  * lon      (lon) int64 0 1 2
  * time     (time) int64 0 1

In [14]: da.stack(latlon=['lat','lon'])
Out[14]: 
<xarray.DataArray (time: 2, latlon: 9)>
array([[ 0.69092373,  0.74086633,  0.08215398,  0.67699002,  0.54688503,
         0.21120849,  0.43816928,  0.10402045,  0.53284326],
       [ 0.94961267,  0.22628054,  0.16806347,  0.86242477,  0.57882117,
         0.68743872,  0.57682212,  0.78923986,  0.23705761]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) int64 0 1
  * latlon   (latlon) object (0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) ...

In [15]: da.stack(latlon=['lat','lon']).groupby('latlon').mean()
Out[15]: 
<xarray.DataArray (latlon: 9)>
array([ 0.8202682 ,  0.48357344,  0.12510872,  0.76970739,  0.5628531 ,
        0.44932361,  0.5074957 ,  0.44663016,  0.38495044])
Coordinates:
  * latlon   (latlon) object (0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you suggest to concat `lat` and `lon` along a new dimension? or along the `nx` dimension? In both cases I think the dimensions of the newly created coordinate are incompatible with the dimensions of the `nl` variable. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: please note that the `nl` variable is *not* two-dimensional. There is a unique dimension (e.g. time). Every nl point along that dimension is associated with a latitude and a longitude. In the `nl` example above the `lat` and `lon` coordinates are parallel, so to speak.

Comment: Just added an example, does that make more sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you propose would work. lat and lon are coordinates but not dimensions. My values are not indexed by (lon, lat, time). As I noted above, there is only one dimension, which is time. My values are indexed by (time), the coordinates as well : lon(time), lat(time).

Comment: I see. I think it might be possible to hack, but the main struggle is going to be the '2d' histogram part - xarray doesn't group by more than one dimension at the moment. So the only way around it is going to be to make one coord / dimension out of two...

Comment: say that I combine lat and lon in a single coord. Since their values are not gridded, I would need to use groupby_bins. Can you apply that function on a set coordinate? How would you define the bins?

Comment: That's the part that's going to be tough. If you wanted to group by unique values of lat & lon, then grouping on a `MultiIndex` would work fine. CC @shoyer, given that I'm out of ideas. You could also try posting on GitHub as an issue / on the mulitdimenional groupby issue

Comment: If you look under the covers, groupby_bins is just groupby on a group make with pandas.cut. You should be able to cut each coordinate lat and lon separately, and then combine them into a single variable like Maximilian suggests.

Comment: @shoyer I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I understand it might be possible to combine both coordinates into a single "combined coordinate". but I don't see how I bin this combined coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/kuchaale/SABER-bin) you can ispire yourself a bit when I was binning SABER satellite data into zonal means, i.e. latitudinally and vertically.